# HOWTO run browser-sync with a web app deployed in JBoss EAP 6.3.3?

Tags: node.js, jboss, jboss6.x, browser-sync

**Issue details**

Is there any specifc steps to run browser-sync with a web app deployed in JBoss EAP 6.3.3 ?

I installed node.js (version 4.4.3 ), i runned `npm install -g browser-sync` .
My web application (MyApp.war) is deployed in my running server JBoss EAP.
I runned `browser-sync start --proxy "http://localhost:8080/MyApp" --files "src/main/webapp/**/*"`
A new browser window is opened with URL http://localhost:3000/MyApp.
However when I changed the content of a file (xhtml,css,js), browser-sync detected it and refresh the browser but no changements appear.

**Please specify which version of Browsersync, node and npm you're running**

```
Browsersync [ 2.12.5 ]
Node [ 4.4.3 ]
Npm [ ]
```

**If CLI, please paste the entire command below**

```
browser-sync start --proxy "http://localhost:8080/MyApp" --files "src/main/webapp/**/*"
```

Thanks